# Populating Table View Cells Creates blank cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am populating a table view with items in a list and when I add multiple items to the table view, all of the cells except the first one is blank. And when I delete the cell lowest to the bottom of the screen, it puts the data from that cell into the next cell up. I'm not sure what I did wrong but here's my code if anyone is able to help.

```
import UIKit

// Initialize the list that populates the each cell in the table view
var list = [AnyObject]()
let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, 
reuseIdentifier: "cell")

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, 
UITableViewDataSource {



@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!



// Declares how many rows the table view will have
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return (list.count)
}

// Populates each table view cell with items from each index in the list
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

//        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
//        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
//        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .natural

    // The text of the cell = the data of index that matches the index of the cell
    cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row] as? String

    // Sets the background color of the cell
//        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    return cell
}

// Allows user to remove item from table view by swiping left
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    // if the user swiped left to delete an item from the table view
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete
    {
        // remove the deleted item from the list and reload the data
        list.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        myTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to find any one of a thousand table view tutorials and look at the proper way to provide a cell from the `cellForRowAt` method.

Comment: @maddy That is what I'm trying to figure out. I've looked at several tutorials. If you could provide some insight as to what I have done wrong with my cellForRowAt method, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a lot of things. First of you need to set the `datasource` and `delegate` of mytableView to self. Also,you need to initialize the `list` array in `viewDidLoad` or any such method that is being called at run time. And once the lists array is being initialized. Then you need to call `myTableView.reloadData()`. Finally your `cellForRow` should look like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) 
    cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row] as? String
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Well I initialized the list outside the class because I needed to access it in another view controller. Same goes for the "let cell=..." line. Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: You have only declared the list as AnyObject but not initialized with values in it. So, after initializing the array you need to call list. Try printing the values inside list.

Comment: I initialized the list with AnyObject because I wanted an empty list that would only contain items that have been added by the user, specifically strings. Also, what does setting the datasource and delegate of the table view to self do? Sorry I'm pretty new at this stuff.

Comment: Since you are new I could suggest some tutorials which you could first go through.

Answer (score 0):

Step I : -  Go to your storyboard.Select FirstViewController scene , select myTableView.
Now select attribute inspector
set "Prototype Cell" value = 1

Now expand "myTableView" and select "cell".
Again select attribute inspector
set identifier value "cell". Now you have done storyboard.
Go to FirstViewController and paste the code below

OR

simply paste the below line in your viewDidLoad()

```
myTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

Both are same

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,
UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!
var list = ["A", "B", "C","A", "B", "f"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myTableView.dataSource = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return (list.count)
}

// Populates each table view cell with items from each index in the list
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    //        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    //        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    //        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .natural

    // The text of the cell = the data of index that matches the index of the cell
    let cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]

    // Sets the background color of the cell
    //        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    return cell
}

// Allows user to remove item from table view by swiping left
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    // if the user swiped left to delete an item from the table view
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete
    {
        // remove the deleted item from the list and reload the data
        list.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        myTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you have not added datasource,     myTableView.dataSource = self. But after adding datasource only with our previous code you will get only single row with list's last value. Hope this definitely will help you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and in case any of the previous answers didn't work: I made most of the set up programatically.

Define global var
`var cellsContent = [String]() // Change to any type you need`

First create the cells with identifiers in viewDidLoad function:

```
cellsContent = ["Text1", "Text2"]
tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
tableView.reloadData()
```

Populate each table view cell with the items in cellsContent var

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
cell.textLabel?.text = cellsContent[indexPath.row] as? String
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

return cell
}
```

Set sections and rows per section

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1 // Change as needed
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cellsContent.count
    }
```